# Text opacity in CSS

Tags: css

Is there any way I could treat text inside of a wordpress widget, to make it semi transparent using an opacity funcion? Only limiting myself to the content of the following code block.

```
#content .widget .caption h3 {
color:#000000;
font-family:'Overlock';
margin:0 -10px;
padding:0 10px;
font-size:27px;
height:46px;
line-height:46px;
font-weight:bold;
```

}

With the option below, the entire widget will be treated as transparent.

```
 #content .widget .caption h3 {
color:#000000;
font-family:'Overlock';
margin:0 -10px;
padding:0 10px;
font-size:27px;
height:46px;
line-height:46px;
font-weight:bold;
opacity:0.2;
```

}

I only want the to have its opacity changed. Is it even possible that way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [rgba](http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/) as the color attribute like this:

```
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

The `0.5` at the end specifiies 50% opacity. This would apply only to the text, and not the containing element.

You've got to watch the [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba)

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like charm! Will be accepted in 15 minutes*

Comment: What is the worst scenario if the browser wont be compatible? Will the text be unformated, or will can it disappear?

Comment: if you add the hex declaration (#000000) just above the rgba, then typically it will just fall back to the first CSS rule instead. Either way it's best to test it on all the browsers you plan to support, so you know exactly what's going to happen, and how things will render on each platform/device.

Answer (score 2):

use `rgba` values:

```
color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.2)
```